# Get out of download mode

Tags: 8.1, samsung-ativ-s, download-mode

I forgot to charge my phone last night and woke up to it out of battery. So I plugged it in to charge (I may or may not have held side buttons to trigger this, I don't remember exactly because I had literally just woken up.) Anyway when it was starting to charge it booted up but after the windows phone splash screen it cut immediately into "download mode."

How do I get it out of this and boot normally?

I'm using windows phone 8.1, the device is a "GT-I8750"[image: download mode]

Answer (score 6):

5 minutes after posting this question I managed to fix it myself. **What I did was held the power button with volume down held simultaneously**, however I don't know if it was this that fixed it or the fact that the phone had more battery at this point. Perhaphs this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this [discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/download-mode/715fb988-ff12-4ea9-8027-96ef82171846?msgId=e6fc815e-5eac-4b0c-a2ec-e7f91a202225) in Microsoft community useful. It states,

> If your phone appears to be stuck in "Download Mode," you may have to
>   be patient. It can take up to 30-40 minutes for your phone to update.
>   If the phone is taking too long to update:
>
> 1. Disconnect the USB cable.
> 2. Remove and reinsert the battery.
> 3. Press the Power button to turn the phone back on.
> 4. Reconnect the USB cable and start the update process again.
>
> You may also be able to correct this problem by using the Windows Phone Support Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Its Ook you just get out of download mode. Pressing and holding power and volume down button simultaneously will move you out from Recovery mode or download mode. What you have done previously was **Entering into download mode** by pressing and holding a combination of keys that puts your device into recovery mode. I don't know what exactly you have pressed but it might be "Power + Volume up" combination as for most of samsung phones